# Subdirectory name condition when loading

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a file structure on HDFS that looks like this:

```
/dir/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$HOUR
```

for instance

```
/dir/2016/03/03/05/file00.txt
```

holds all files for March 3, 2016 05:00

When I run my PIG script I want to load all files for a certain day that are **before** a certain hour.

For example, when I run

```
pig -p YEAR=2016 -p MONTH=03 -p DAY=03 -p HOUR=05 pig_script.pig
```

I want the script to load all files in:

```
/dir/2016/03/03/00/
/dir/2016/03/03/01/ 
/dir/2016/03/03/02/
/dir/2016/03/03/03/
/dir/2016/03/03/04/
```

But not including 05:00 or any later hours of that day.

Is there a regexp that I can use?

Would love some help.

Thanks,
Yulia.

Comment: I guess it should be doable using globs (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch05s02.html). For this kind of use case you might want to look into Oozie though which allows you to specify input datasets in a very elaborate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite what you were looking for, but may be helpful. PigStorage supports the parameters:

```
-tagFile
-tagPath
```

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html

Those would prepend the file and path name to your relation. Then you can easily filter out the rows which come from directories you are not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Apart form what Ran suggested, incase you are looking for custom behaviour, You can use custom Load/Store UDFs to implement your logic. You can pass custom input params (year, month, date, hour) to the loader to pick up all of the input paths that you desire.

See [this](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html#load-store-functions) for further details.